# Searching for org-mode property values including whitespace

Tags: org-mode

I made this simple example to help explain my problem:

```
* entry
  :PROPERTIES:
  :author1:  me
  :author2:  my self
  :END:
```

Now when I do a property search with `C-c a m` searching `author1="me"` I find `entry` as expected.

When I try to search `author2="my self"` as soon as I hit space to type in the whitespace character between my and self it just says `[No match]` in the minibuffer and the whitespace character is not inserted. I can find `entry` by searching `author2={self}` for example or type the whitespace outside the minibuffer and copy-paste it in, but that can't be the solution... I can type in whitespace normally in other minibuffers, e.g. in the keyword search under `C-c a s`.

I tried typing in a search like that launching `emacs -q`, so without any emacs customization but got the same result. I have emacs 26.3.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have to quote the space as you are typing it in with `C-q`: `author2="myC-q  self"RET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out (thanks to `C-h k`) that space is bound to some autocomplete function in that instance of the minibuffer by default.

So the easy solution was to add

`(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map (kbd "SPC") 'self-insert-command)`

to the init file to have space act as space in the tag search.

@NickD: thanks for the comment, it helped me understand that space must just be bound to some weird function in the minibuffer and remember that I know how to figure out which function it is ;)

Comment: BTW, you can accept your own answer (assuming it works for you :-) ).

Comment: @NickD Apparently, I'm allowed to do so only by tomorrow, but I'll do it then. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks, I've had the same problem. And now it works.

Comment: Thanks -- I was having the same problem. HOWEVER, I've settled on @NickD's suggestion of preceding the space with C-q. That's because I found that I had been relying on the default binding to 'minibuffer-complete-word a lot more than I'd realized (e.g. for completion of function names in the minibuffer), and so switching it to 'self-insert-command tripped me up a lot. Did you stick with the new binding as-is, or did you by any chance find a way to have that particular binding be in some way context sensitive -- i.e. so that it only operated in the context of org-tags-view (i.e. C-c a m)?